# Proper management of PGPool II

Tags: failover, postgresql

Currently I have a site, with one Postgres database server. It is just for a select number of users (less than ten) but it needs the maximum uptime possible.

I would like some kind of automatic failover for the database.

So I was thinking something like: one server running PGPool II, one running Postgres as master, one running Postgres as slave. But then, if wherever PGPool is running suddenly loses power (or dies, or whatever), there's a single point of failure and the whole thing goes down.

Is there a solution, assuming that outsourcing this to someone else isn't possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that is certain is that there must be at least two machines running `pgpool`. How you achieve this depends - there is no solution universally applicable to all cases. If what you have is a web application, then you must also run the web application in at least two machines, so you could make something like this:

```
            +----------+  +---------+
            | pgmaster |  | pgslave |
            +----------+  +---------+
                 |             |
      +----------+-------------+-----------+ 
      |                                    |
+-----|----+                         +-----|----+
|  pgpool  |                         |  pgpool  |
|     |    |                         |     |    |
|  webapp  |                         |  webapp  |
+-----|----+                         +-----|----+
      |                                    |
   internet                             internet
```

(In that case you also need some kind of failover on the client side - the one I've marked as "internet".)

If, on the other hand, you really need, not a highly available web application (or similar service), but a highly available postgresql (to which any client can connect anytime), then an alternative is

```
            +----------+  +---------+
            | pgmaster |  | pgslave |
            +----------+  +---------+
                 |             |
      +----------+-------------+-----------+ 
      |                                    |
+-----|----+                         +-----|----+
|  pgpool  |                         |  pgpool  | (standby)
+-----|----+                         +-----|----+
      |                                    |  
  Failover
  IP address
      |
    client
```

The `pgpool`, in that case, could also be in the same machine as the databases. What is important is that you need some kind if IP address failover, which could be `keepalived`, but the exact solutions available depend on lower level networking details of the data center you are using (for example, `keepalived` can't work in Hetzner, as they have a different way of switching failover IPs). Also note that in this case connected clients probably *will* disconnect in case of failover, but they will able to reconnect immediately.

Also note that there are other difficulties, one of them being that you can't rule out network partitioning, where both PostgreSQL machines will be working and connected, but they will have somehow lost connection to each other, so each one of them will think the other is dead, and therefore each one will decide to be a master. To address this issue, I know of three solutions: 1) STONITH, which requires special hardware; 2) Quorums, which require special software (such as corosync/pacemaker); 3) Manual failover (the admins get notified and the system is broken until they decide how to fix it). However, it could be not too difficult to setup a quorum if you use my proposed scheme above, but with three `pgpool`s instead of two; but I don't remember if `pgpool` supports that.

Bottom line: high availability can be difficult and expensive. Carefully examine the possibility of avoiding it altogether. If you can't, be prepared to study much and design much and redesign much, and be aware it's going to take a lot of time.

Comment: Have you actually implemented PGPool with keepalived? I am currently trying to make this work.

Comment: @thanasisk No, sorry.